# Not Able To View HTML Using GNOME Yelp

Tags: gnome, yelp, doc

In the GNOME Yelp docs, it says that Yelp supports viewing HTML. But when I run `yelp file:///home/myusername/Desktop/test.html`, it displays "The URL can't be shown."

How can I resolve it? Actually I want to view my docs offline which I've converted into HTML from markdown.

Using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Is it "\" or "/"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1443179).

You can use any lightweight web-browser like `epiphany-browser` for this purpose.